# C++ the program won't end

Tags: c++, loops

Can you tell what is the mistake? It compiles and runs ok but the program won't end.

I am using dev c++. The code is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

main()
{

    char num;
again:

    int usr;
    float area;

    cout << "\nEnter 1 to calculate area of rectangle\n";
    cout << "Enter 2 to calculate area of trapezoid\n";
    cout << "\nEnter your choice: ";
    cin >> usr;

    if (usr == 1)
    {
        double width, length;
        cout << "Enter the width of rectangle: ";
        cin >> width;
        cout << "Enter the length of rectangle: ";
        cin >> length;
        area = length * width;
        cout << "The area of rectangle is: " << area;
    }

    if (usr == 2) {
        double base1, base2, height;
        cout << "Enter the base 1 of trapezoid: ";
        cin >> base1;
        cout << "Enter the base 2 of trapezoid: ";
        cin >> base2;
        cout << "Enter the height of trapezoid: ";
        cin >> height;
        area = (((base1 + base2) / 2) * height);
        cout << "The area of trapezoid is: " << area;
    }

    cout << "\n\ndo you want to do another calculation?";
    cin >> num;
    {
        goto again;
    }

    if (num == 'y')
    {
        goto again;
    }

    if (num == 'n') {
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you expect `cin >> num; { goto again; }` to do?

Comment: I said you should improve it first

Comment: if i remove the brackets its end and wont ask 2nd time i want it to ask again if i say 'y' yes it should do calculation again and when i say 'n' no it exits but it wont exit its start it again

Answer (score 5):

**Never** ever use `goto`, unless you have a very good reason to (which you don't).

```
cin >> num;{
goto again;
}
```

I have no idea why you wrote that, but that's the problem. If you would have written it with proper formatting, it would have looked like this

```
cin >> num;
{
    goto again;
}
```

The bracket `{}` just changes the scope (useful for variables and such), but doesn't do anything else. The `goto again;` still gets executed, so you run into an endless loop.

The 2 conditions after it are fine, so just removing `{ goto again; }` will "fix" your issue.

Comment: should i remove it or can you fix it for me please check it let me know any other mistake in it

Comment: @AnamMiR if you remove it it will work, because the `if`s after are ok, so your program will exit.

Comment: cout <<"\n\ndo you want to do another calculation?";
   cin >> num;
   goto again;

   if (num=='y')


   goto again;

   if(num=='n'){
   exit (0);}
}

Comment: @AnamMiR nope, you have to remove **everything** in the brackets, including the brackets, so also the `goto again;` after `cin >> num;`.

Comment: if i remove the brackets its end and wont ask 2nd time i want it to ask again if i say 'y' yes it should do calculation again and when i say 'n' no it exits but it wont exit its start it again

Comment: @AnamMiR it works for me. Are you sure you only removed `{ goto again; }` ?

Comment: if i remove the brackets its end and wont ask 2nd time i want it to ask again if i say 'y' yes it should do calculation again and when i say 'n' no it exits but it wont exit its start it again

Answer (score 0):

Remove line no 44 in your code

your code

```
cin >> num;{
goto again;
 }
```

Solution remove

> goto again

```
cin >> num;{

 }
```

This will solve your problem

Comment: Are you sure about those brackets after `cin >> num;`?  What purpose do they serve?

Comment: you can remove the brackets.

Comment: can  can one help to rewrite and exit the program

Comment: if i remove the brackets its end and wont ask 2nd time i want it to ask again if i say 'y' yes it should do calculation again and when i say 'n' no it exits but it wont exit its start it again

Comment: It's working fine for me after removing the brackets.

Comment: can u email me how u have done anam.mir46@hotmail.com

Comment: i am using dev c++

Comment: i want it to run again n when i say no it shouldnt